# Chrome search bar automatically uses old search terms

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

I have a problem with my google chrome: When I try to search for a term which starts with a string  that I previously searched for, that old search term is automatically used. So, assuming I searched for "foo fighters" last week and today I want to search for "foo", when I press Ctrl-L, type "foo" then my search will be "foo fighters" instead of "foo". Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: See also [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/741036/), if you are using the Chrome LastPass plugin.

Answer (score 3):

From: https://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95656

> The prediction service is turned on by
>   default. Follow these steps to turn it
>   off:
>
> 1. Click the wrench icon tools menu on the browser toolbar.
> 2. Select Options (Preferences on Mac and Linux; Settings on Chrome OS).
> 3. Click the Under the Hood tab.
> 4. In the "Privacy" section, deselect the "Use a prediction service
>      to help complete searches and URLs
>      typed in the address bar" checkbox.
>
> Keep in mind that the address bar
>   shows matches from your browsing
>   history, in addition to predictions.
>   **If you don't want to see matches from
>   your browsing history, clear your
>   browsing history.**

Emphasis added to that last sentence, its important!!

Comment: Actually, seeing the results from the history isn't bad. It also wouldn't be a problem to /see/ the prediction results, just not have them used automatically when pressing return :) This worked for me, thanks

Comment: Awesomesauce, glad it worked for you :-) *drools at the imminent +100 bounty*

Comment: @PriceChild: Not unless Chris Neuroth presses the Bounty button ...

Comment: Couldn't award the bounty because of a 2 hours block. Now I have a problem: the old behavior is back :( Probably it uses the history now to autocomplete... Will investigate further :/

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure this only happens on one of my computers, have to check that again. This issue is really weird, I don't really believe (or hope ;)) it's intended behavior...

Comment: Oh, and clearing the history is not an optoin. I like my history to get suggestions - I just want to be able to ignore them without pressing "delete" before "return" on every search ;)

Comment: ... and after googling a little more, it seems this really is intended behavior... As a workaround, hitting space after your search term will do, but it's still really annoying.

Comment: Bah foiled again! :-) Hmm yeah I'm not sure... I'll have a think and get back to you! There's always a way.

Comment: Hmm I think I'm ready to give up I'm afraid. I did have a look at `C:\Documents and Settings\PriceChild\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\` and saw a couple of possibly useful options, e.g. `search: {"suggest_enabled": true}` in `Default\Preferences` but anything I change is reset when loading Chrome. I think if you want to keep your browsing history you just have to be careful and not blindly hit enter without checking the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I just use "foo", <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the location bar for search. Try the extension "No History". This will stop google chrome from remembering anything you type in there. (Or from displaying it at least).

(You can also always use Preferences | Under the Hood | Clear Browsing Data)